# More efficient/appropriate way to write this code?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

So I have just recently started learning about responsive web design and using media queries in my CSS. I've gotten it to where I understand how to make things responsive and optimized decently for phones.

If anyone is just bored or would be interested in looking at this, could you maybe tell me if I'm on the right track or if I'm breaking any serious coding rules? Ha.

Here's a portion of what I'm working on: (this is referring to the little box that moves, just ignore the background)

```css
<style>
  
  .three img {
   position: relative;
    top: 0;
  }
  
  #shoutout{
    position: absolute;
    margin: 40% 45%;
    border: 2px solid black;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 7% 14%;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  
  .sotext p{
   font-size: 120%;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  @media screen and (max-width: 1023px){
     #shoutout{
       text-align: center;
       font-size: 75%;
       margin-top: 40%;
    }
    
    .sotext p{
       text-align: center;
       font-size: 100%;
    }
  }
  
  @media screen and (max-width: 740px){
    #shoutout{
       text-align: center;
       margin-top: 35%;
       margin-left: 45%;
    }
    
    .sotext p{
       text-align: center;
       font-size: 60%;
    }
  }
</style>
```

```html
<head>
  <!-- Header Placeholder-->
</head>

<body>
  
  <div>
    <section id="shoutout">
        <!-- shoutut box -->
          <div class="sotext">
            <p>Placeholder Text</p>
          </div>
    </section>
    <section class="three">
      <img       src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/55bed56ee4b04fdc6e0dd0d8/t/575d8fed4d088eb0ab810e52/1465749487419/mother_daughter.png" alt="shoutout image" />
    </section>
  </div>
  
<body>
```

Comment: Remove the duplication, .sotext p is already aligned center, you only add the elements that change in media queries, the rest stay the same. Basically you want to give your elements all the code they need in the base element, then adjust the ones that need adjusting in the media queries.

Comment: This might be a better fit on [**CodeReview**](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) but check their posting guidelines first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minor tweaks

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.background {
  background-image:url(http://static1.squarespace.com/static/55bed56ee4b04fdc6e0dd0d8/t/575d8fed4d088eb0ab810e52/1465749487419/mother_daughter.png);
  background-position: center left;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%;
}

#shoutout{
    position: absolute;
    margin: 40% 45%;
    border: 2px solid black;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 7% 14%;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  
  .sotext p{
   font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  @media screen and (max-width: 1023px){
     #shoutout{
       text-align: center;
       font-size: 0.75em;
       margin-top: 40%;
    }
    
    .sotext p{
       font-size: 1em;
    }
  }
  
  @media screen and (max-width: 740px){
    #shoutout{
       margin-top: 35%;
       margin-left: 45%;
    }
    
    .sotext p{
       font-size: 0.6em;
    }
  }
```

```html
  <div class="background">
    <section id="shoutout">
        <!-- shoutut box -->
          <div class="sotext">
            <p>Placeholder Text</p>
          </div>
    </section>
  </div>
```

I'd personally use background-image instead of img tags, gives you a little more control over display. I'd also use ems instead of percentage for font size. And as I said in my comments drop the duplication.

Comment: Ah, thanks for noticing the duplication. I didn't even realize I had done that. Making the image a background image is a great idea, especially since I'm not doing anything special with it. What exactly is the difference between ems and %'s? Do they just respond better?

Comment: More personal preference and common use than anything. This is a nice article on the whole thing http://kyleschaeffer.com/development/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/

Comment: and I just read that article and it says to use % lol. To each their own, although that article is from 7 years ago.

Comment: Awesome well, thanks! I'll delete this post now before people keep downvoting my question...I don't quite understand this community lol

Comment: lol they can be picky. Technically they want just questions that are actually problems you can't solve, not just opinion based things. Have a nice night Ben!!

Comment: You as well, Rick! Thanks again.